# ffmpeg video thumbnail size

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm generating thumbnails like so:

```
exec(ffmpeg -itsoffset -4  -i '.$path.' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 300x300 '.$other_path);
```

Is it possible to not specify the exact size of output image and set it to 100%?

Comment: Yes. Just remove `-s 300x300`. Also, you should probably use `-f image2` instead of `-f rawvideo` and you don't need `-an`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the -s 300x300 option, and it will note resize.

Comment: I already tried that but it's not doing anything, edit: I had typo there that's why I didn't work :-) thanks